# find width of path

Tags: geometry

suppose we have following question

A square garden is surrounded by a path of uniform width. If the path and the garden both have an area of $x$, then what is the width of the path in terms of $x$?

so we have following picture right

[image]

because we dont know if   path of uniform width is square or not how can i find  width?if area of square is $x$,then  length is $\sqrt{x}$,but what about second figure?suppose it's length are $a$ and $b$,then $a*b=x$,then how can i continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have

$$4 w \sqrt{x} + 4 w^2 = x$$

(i.e., four rectangles + four squares that make up path, width of path = $w$)

Solve for $w$:

$$2 w = \frac{-\sqrt{x} \pm \sqrt{2 x}}{2}$$

Choose the positive solution:

$$w=\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{4} \sqrt{x}$$

Comment: a little detailed please

Comment: @dato: where are you having trouble understanding this solution?  The setup or the algebra?

Comment: setup of course,what is denoting by what?

Comment: $w$ is the unknown path width.  $x$ is, as you denoted, the area of both the garden and the path.

Comment: but  i saw,why it is  equal to $x$,we already eliminated it,it should equal to zero,is not it

Comment: @dato: No idea what you mean.  The area of the path is the sum of the areas of a) four rectangles, each of width $w$ and length $\sqrt{x}$, and b) four squares, each of side $w$.  The area of this path is, as your problem specifies, equal to $x$.  That is what the first equation states.  You get a quadratic in $w$; solve.

Comment: if we denote width by $w$,then  we have $(2*w+\sqrt{x})(2*w+\sqrt{x})=x$  is it correct?

Comment: @dato: I don't see how this is correct; this would be the area of the garden + path, so you could have $(2 w+\sqrt{x})^2 = 2 x$, which is equivalent to my first equation.

Comment: no no why it is equal to  $2*x$?length  of  path is equal $2*w+\sqrt{x}$,width is also same,product of them is $x$

Comment: outer area is simple length *width ,is not it?

Comment: @dato: either you understand the problem you posed or you do not.  The area of the inner square is $x$; so is the area of the path.  Therefore, the area of the big square is $x+x=2 x$.  I do not know what else there is to say about this, nor do I know how to help you further.

Comment: that is what i have not understand,area of path  is different then area of big figure?

Comment: @dato: **yes!!!**

Comment: then  it should be mentioned in problem right,on path i have considered as  square itself

Comment: i think that such kind of problems  should be a little more detailed described,for non native speakers

Answer (score 1):

Call the width of the path $a$.

Like you say, the width of the inner square is $\sqrt{x}$. The width (and height) of the outer square is then $2a+\sqrt{x}$.

1. What is the area of the outer square?
2. What is the area of the path?
3. What can you conclude about $a$?

Comment: sorry we are denoting with as a  full length of  half part?

Comment: I'm denoting by $a$ the width of one part of the path (so that if you draw a horizontal line through the middle of your figure, the first segment has length $a$, then $x$, then $a$ again.)

Answer (score 1):

Define 
$$\begin{align}
g &:= \text{width of garden (inner square)} \\
w &:= \text{width of path} \\
s &:=  \text{width of outer square} = g + 2 w
\end{align}$$

Then
$$\begin{align}
\text{area of garden (inner square)} &= g^2 \\
\text{area of path (outer sq., minus inner sq.)} &= s^2 - g^2 \\
&= ( g + 2 w )^2 - g^2 \\
&= g^2 + 4 g w + 4 w^2 - g^2 \\
&= 4 w^2 + 4 g w
\end{align}$$

We know that each of the two areas equals $x$. For notational simplicity, temporarily write "$y$" for "$\sqrt{x}$", so that $x = y^2$.
$$\begin{align}
g^2 &= x = y^2 &(1) \\
4 w^2 + 4 g w &= x = y^2 &(2)
\end{align}$$

From equation $(1)$, we get that $g = y$. Substituting that into $(2)$ gives
$$4 w^2 + 4 w y = y^2 \qquad \to \qquad 4 w^2 + 4 w y - y^2 = 0$$

Now, simply solve the quadratic equation for $w$:

$$w = \frac{- 4 y \pm \sqrt{(4y)^2-4\cdot 4\cdot(-y^2)}}{2\cdot 4} = \frac{-4y \pm \sqrt{16y^2+16y^2}}{8} = \frac{-4y\pm 4y\sqrt{2}}{8} = \frac{y}{2}\left(-1\pm\sqrt{2}\right)$$

We (presumably) want the positive root, so (since $\sqrt{2} > 1$) take "$\pm$" to be "$+$"; also, replace "$y$" with its defined value, "$\sqrt{x}$":

$$w = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\left(\sqrt{2} - 1\right)$$

Comment: thanks very much for your help